# Find the length of PQ.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

---

Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Let the external bisector of angle $A$ meet the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$ again at $M \neq A$. A circle with centre $M$ and radius $MB$ meets the internal bisector of angle $A$ at points $P$ and $Q$. Determine the length of $PQ$ in terms of the lengths of $AB$ and $AC$.

Could anyone please provide a solution? I cannot seem to make any significant progress in the question.

Edit: Here is the original project that I created in Geogebra. Hope it makes the diagram clearer.

https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ezted9sg

Comment: Nice formatting of question; nice diagram.  Re "...I cannot seem to make any significant progress...", please edit your query to show all of the work that you have done so far.

Comment: It is basic angle chasing and most of it is just me making sense of the diagram. And a big mess of trigonometric expressions. I do not want to include this as I want an elegant answer to the question.

Comment: I regard your response as reasonable.  However, the first thing that mathSE reviewers will focus on is that you haven't shown your work.  A mathSE reference on this issue is https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.  Also, please use mathJax to format your math.  A mathSE reference on this is https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: I am very sorry, but typing that out would be a nightmare, especially to a novice like me. And I do use Mathjax (same as Latex, right?)

Comment: Mathjax has some minor differences with Latex.  Use <br> to force line break.  Also, Mathjax can only be invoked by enclosing the characters in `$...$` or `$$...$$`.  Thus, for example to underline text via mathJax rather than html tags, you have to do something like `$\underline{\text{abc}}$`.

Comment: With respect to "...would be a nightmare...", is the nightmare re the level of detail required or your unfamiliarity with mathJax.  If mathJax is the problem, what about creating a latex (*.tex) document, using something like pdflatex to convert it into a pdf file and then **either** uploading the pdf file to the internet and providing a link to it in your query (so others can see your **detailed** work) or creating a graphics file (e.g. *.jpg file) by (for example) screen capturing your latex-pdf file.  Then,you could embed the image directly into your query. ...see next comment

Comment: At mathSE, reviewers will dislike that they can't "search" on your work (re my previous comment).  However, they won't dislike it as much as your showing no work.  Therefore, if the "nightmare" is in actually showing your work, I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prove this..

•Find the length of $MA=2R\cos(\frac{A+2C}{2})$ first. ( Where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle.)

•Then find $MB=2R\cos(\frac{A}{2})$ by using Sine Law (Chase the angles) in $\triangle MAB$

•Finally apply Pythagoras theorem in $\triangle MAQ$

$MQ^2-MA^2=MB^2-MA^2=AQ^2$ and $PQ=2AQ$

Comment: But what is Angie AMB?

Comment: It is equal to angle ACB.

Comment: Oh sorry I am an idiot

Comment: Well I did get an expression but it is not pretty. Something horrific in terms of sines of angles B and C

Comment: Can you post what did you get? When I was doing it, I replaced $\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=2R$...See if this helps.

Comment: $AQ=\frac{AB}{\sin C} \cdot \cos \frac{A}{2} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{A}{2}+C\right)$

Comment: I think you have a mistake somewhere..I am getting $AQ^2=4R^2\sin(C)\sin(B)=bc$

Comment: How did you find the length of $MA$ then?

Comment: The answer that you got is indeed the right answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112111/discussion-between-user35508-and-popular-power).